# MWS API _POST_ORDER_FULFILLMENT_DATA_ feed does not updating tracking info

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I am trying to update tracking info using MWS API with feeds API and feedSubmision method,

When I send the request I obtain submitFeedID and when I call getFeedSubmisionResult, the status is "DONE" but nothing happens in the order that I want to update and no error is reported in XML.

Here my XML feed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
  <Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
    <MerchantIdentifier>XXXXXXXXXXX</MerchantIdentifier>
  </Header>
  <MessageType>OrderFulfillment</MessageType>
  <Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
    <OrderFulfillment>
      <AmazonOrderID>XXX-XXXXXXX-XXXXXXX</AmazonOrderID>
      <FulfillmentDate>2020-10-14T11:09:52+00:00</FulfillmentDate>
      <FulfillmentData>
        <CarrierName>CARRIER</CarrierName>
        <CarrierCode>CODE</CarrierCode>
        <ShippingMethod>METHOD</ShippingMethod>
        <ShipperTrackingNumber>XXXXXXXXXXXXX</ShipperTrackingNumber>
      </FulfillmentData>
    </OrderFulfillment>
  </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Could someone help me? I don't know how can I update tracking info because no errors found in response.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Done!

with Amazon MWS Scratchpad I had could obtain the error message and the problem was the date.

I needed to inform +02 not +00.

Moreover the carrier code  was not compatible with carrier name.